# dust js partials not working inside loop

Tags: dust.js

I'm trying to do something similar to the below code.(trying to print an partial inside a loop)

```
    {#projects
     {<greeting}
       Hello {.name}
     {/greeting}
    {/projects}
```

But im getting an output like below:

```
Hello
Hello
....
```

As you can see that partial is not printed inside the loop.

My actual code http://jsfiddle.net/WKxzb/1/

Answer (score 1):

Most of the documentation examples suggest something like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cnftm/

In short, in `greeting.tl`:

```
Hello, {name}!
```

then in `projects.tl`:

```
{#projects}
  {>greeting /}
{/projects}
```

If where you store `name` didn't happen to be named `name`:

```
{#projects}
  {>greeting name=someOtherVar /}
{/projects}
```

Anything you want to be parametrized has to be, ahem, passed as a parameter, and no body is supported.

The exception to these is [blocks with inline partials](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#wiki-Blocks_and_Inline_Partials), which are like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PWYBr/1/

In short, in `greeting.tl`:

```
Hello, {+name}Anonymous Coward{/name}!{~n}
```

then in `projects.tl`:

```
{#projects}
    {>greeting/}
    {<name}
        {name}
    {/name}
{/projects}
```

This works great for loops, but you can't reuse the greeting partial ANYWHERE else on the page... basically, whoever writes `{<name}` *last* wins, such that this will do weird things:

```
{>greeting/}
{<name}everybody{/name}

{#projects}
    {>greeting/}
    {<name}
        {name}
    {/name}
{/projects}
```